# Why Boost Graph Library doesn't have its own namespace?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces

Many, maybe even most, Boost libraries have their own namespaces, like:

```
boost::tuples
boost::lambda
boost::math
```

These examples show that even very frequently used, general purpose libraries have their own namespaces. Why then a specialized library like Boost Graph Library resides in top `boost` namespace?

Comment: I can only guess here, but it seems that the older libraries didn't do the sub-namespacing thing. Some have adopted it later, but BGL isn't such a library

Comment: Close-voters, this is not opinion based. At some point a design decision was made, for good or bad reasons. The fact that people may like to give opinions about matters they know nothing about does not make the question opinion based.

Comment: It does make it hard to answer with any authority. This would be a good question to address at the boost dev mailing list then

Comment: This is early, v1.18. April 2000, as archive.org can show.  All the old stuff is in the boost namespace, like basic_regex and array, etc.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you. I was going to write a similar comment, but you expressed it more eloquently.